# How to use sample weights with data augmentation in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, theano

I'm trying to use sample weighting with `ImageGenerator` in a pixelwise segmentation task.

- images and masks are numpy arrays (634, 1, 64, 64)
- masks have 5 classes (encoded as 0 to 4)
- `sample_weight` is an array (634, 64, 64)
- data augmentation using `.flow` for 2 generators with identical `seed=42`  and `batch_size=32`
- model being compiled with `sample_weight_mode='temporal'`
- last 3 layers in the Unet model are:

  ```
  conv2d_19 (Conv2D)  (None, 5, 64, 64)     325        
  dropout_18[0][0]                 

  conv2d_20 (Conv2D)  (None, 1, 64, 64)     6          
  conv2d_19[0][0]                  

  activation_1 (Activation) (None, 1, 64, 64)     0
  conv2d_20[0][0]
  ```

This throws an error:

`ValueError: Found a sample_weight array with shape (634, 64, 64). In order to use timestep-wise sample weighting, you should pass a 2D sample_weight array.`

If I reshape `sample_weight` to (634, 4096) I get:

`ValueError: Found a sample_weight array with shape (634, 4096) for an input with shape (32, 1, 64, 64). sample_weight cannot be broadcast.`

Is this my misunderstanding of how to use `ImageGenerator` or is it unable to handle this particular situation?

If I do not use sample weights, the model runs and no errors are thrown.

Keras 2.0.4, Theano 0.9

Answer (score 1):

The Keras sample weights take as input a 1D array (one weight per feature) in default mode, and a 2D array in temporal mode. The temporal mode could work for you, but you would need to make the following changes. Basically, Keras does not support 3D weights, so you have to flatten your 64x64 images at the input, and reshape your tensor to 2D before the convolutional layers.

1) reshape sample_weight to 634,4096

2) add an input layer with which accepts a flattened image 4096 pixels long : Keras will now accept per pixel weights, considering the pixels as a temporal sequence (a 1D signal)

3) add a Reshape layer before the first 2D convolution